# Navigating Through a DataSet

Tags: vb.net, dataset

```
' Create two instances of the `DataTable` object to reference the two tables

Dim tblCategories As DataTable = DS.Tables("Categories")
Dim tblProducts As DataTable = DS.Tables("Products")

' Create two DataColumn objects to reference the columns on which the relation is based

Dim colCatCategoryID As DataColumn = tblCategories.Columns("CategoryID")
Dim colProdCategoryID As DataColumn = tblProducts.Columns("CategoryID")
```

When I get to `Dim colCatCategoryID As DataColumn = tblCategories.Columns("CategoryID")` I get the following error message:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Debug your code.  It sounds like there is no "CategoryID" column or no table named "Categories" in the DataSet.  use your mouse to find out which one is `Nothing`

Comment: BTW that first bit does not `Create two instances of the DataTable object` it attempts to create  references to 2 *different* table objects.  It is not clear why you need this since `DS.Tables(n)` is the same thing.